# (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) nuget restore failed

Tags: jenkins, nuget

We run nuget restore on a Windows slave using Jenkins as build server. When the slave service runs as a user instead System account then the `nuget restore` may fail with

```
Error parsing solution file at d:\jenkins\tools\ci-home\workspace\t_im-server_feature_os-jenkins_2\IM-Server.sln: Catastrophic failure (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED)) nuget restore failed
```

We run the following command:

```
%NuGetExe% restore "%PathServer%SC.InputManagement.sln" -PackagesDirectory "%PathServer%packages" 1>%LogFile% 2>&1
```

The solution file is fine, cause if login to the build server and run `nuget restore` this simply works fine. I thought the jenkins-user might not have permissions on the folder but he has full control over the complete folder.

We use `NuGet.exe 5.3.1.6268`

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the `package`-folder from the workspace helped.

I suspect a permission issue with the `package`-folder as I went into the project folder with my user and ran `nuget restore` manually for testing.

Maybe not the best idea...